# Why are nameservers needed in resolv.conf?

Tags: networking, dns, etc

I know what a nameserver is. But can anyone explain why nameservers need to be specified in `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: I can't get what is your question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's necessary because it helps your computer convert between names like `google.com` to their actual ip address and dial those addresses. Since Ubuntu uses `dnsmasq`, it will handle writing to `/etc/resolv.conf` but traditionally if you didn't have `dnsmasq` you had to write nameserver by yourself.